# Cannot convert source interface type to target interface type

Tags: c#, interface

I want to process files as they are saved in four directories, they all processed in very different ways.

I have a common processor IFileQueueService that runs on a dispatch timer, loads all the file names and calls a custom processor IExecutionProcessor for each file. This might be a simple question but I have processors with more properties than the standard IExecutionProvider and I am not sure how to call those custom processors.

```
//Basic processor interface
public interface IExecutionProvider
{
    void ProcessFile(string file);
}

//Simplified version of one of the custom processor interfaces
public interface IKyoExecutionProcessor
{
    string DestinationPath { get; set; }
}

public class KyoExecutionProcessor : IExecutionProvider, IKyoExecutionProcessor
{
   //This processor moves a file to the DestinationPath.
}

public interface IFileQueueService
{
    string SourcePath { get; set; }
    IExecutionProvider ExecutionProvider { get; set; }
    void Start();
    void Stop();
}

public class FileProcessor : IFileQueueService
{
    ...
    public virtual void ProcessFileQueue()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> filesToProcess = GetFilesReadyToProcess();
        foreach (string file in filesToProcess.ToList())
        {
            ExecutionProvider.ProcessFile(file);
        }
    }
}

public class KYOFileSysWatcher : ServiceBase
{
    private IFileQueueService Processor { get; set; }
    private IKyoExecutionProcessor KyoCustomProcessor { get; set; }

    public KYOFileSysWatcher()
    {
        Processor = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IFileQueueService>();
        KyoCustomProcessor = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IKyoExecutionProcessor>();

        //This doesn't work, cannot convert source type to target type, but it implements the IExecutionProvider interface??? How do I do this?
        Processor.ExecutionProvider = KyoCustomProcessor;

        Processor.Start(); //Sets up dispatch timer
    }

 }
```

Comment: How does `KyoCustomProcessor` implement `IExecutionProvider`? It is explicitly an `IKyoExecutionProcessor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics to the rescue ...

```
//Basic processor interface
public interface IExecutionProvider
{
    void ProcessFile(string file);
}

//Simplified version of one of the custom processor interfaces
public interface IKyoExecutionProcessor
{
    string DestinationPath { get; set; }
}

public interface IFileQueueService<TProvider>
    where TProvider : IExecutionProvider
{
    string SourcePath { get; set; }
    TProvider ExecutionProvider { get; set; }
    void Start();
    void Stop();
}

public class FileProcessor<TProvider> : IFileQueueService<TProvider>
    where TProvider : IExecutionProvider
{
    string[] GetFilesReadyToProcess() { return new string[0]; }
    public TProvider ExecutionProvider { get; set; }

    public virtual void ProcessFileQueue()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> filesToProcess = GetFilesReadyToProcess();
        foreach (string file in filesToProcess.ToList())
        {
            ExecutionProvider.ProcessFile(file);
        }
    }

    #region IFileQueueService<TProvider> Members

    public string SourcePath { get; set; }
    public void Start() { }
    public void Stop() { }

    #endregion
}

public class KyoExecutionProcessor : IExecutionProvider, IKyoExecutionProcessor
{
    //This processor moves a file to the DestinationPath.
    public string DestinationPath { get; set; }
    public void ProcessFile(string file) { }
}

public class ServiceBase<TProcessor>
    where TProcessor : IExecutionProvider
{
    protected FileProcessor<TProcessor> Processor { get; set; }
    protected TProcessor CustomProcessor { get; set; }
}

public class KYOFileSysWatcher : ServiceBase<KyoExecutionProcessor>
{
    public KYOFileSysWatcher()
    {
        Processor = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<FileProcessor<KyoExecutionProcessor>>();
        CustomProcessor = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<KyoExecutionProcessor>();

        //This compiles now!
        Processor.ExecutionProvider = CustomProcessor;

        Processor.Start(); //Sets up dispatch timer
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted the first answer before I saw yours but thank you for it. I'll implement your version. +1 for your answer.

Comment: You can change the accepted answer if you want, I think. Thanks for the +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your `IKyoExecutionProcessor` interface should derive from `IExecutionProvider` like this:

```
public interface IKyoExecutionProcessor : IExecutionProvider 
{
    string DestinationPath { get; set; }
}
```

This makes sure that there is a 'is-a' relation between interfaces, which will also enable you to implement `KyoExecutionProcessor` class like this:

```
public class KyoExecutionProcessor : IKyoExecutionProcessor
{
   public void ProcessFile(string file) { ... }
   public string DestinationPath { get; set; }
}
```

This way, any object that implements `IKyoExecutionProcessor` can be assigned to a variable of type `IExecutionProvider`.

```
Processor.ExecutionProvider = KyoCustomProcessor; // You can now appoint IKyoExecutionProcessor instance to IExecutionProvider variable
```